# Android device compatibility with Samsung galaxy S3 after publishing

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest, compatibility, galaxy

I have an issue on my application after I published it on the play store (Beta test).
I've tested the `app-debug` and the `app-release` apks on multiple AVDs and even on my S3 mobile, everything worked fine. Then I load the `app-release.apk` file for Beta test and my S3 mobile is no more compatible with the app.
Do you have any suggestion? I added several layout and values files but no result.  Here are my manifest file and a capture of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxxxx">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
```

I also tried this but i got the same results

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

You can find the project structure here:

[image: Directory structure]

Here is the content of the build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 23  
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com."
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Can you include the logcat/packagemanager error when trying to install the apk?

Comment: Can you also add to your question the contents of your build.gradle file?

Comment: @petey Added the content of the build.gradle

Comment: this might fix it....consider updating the `buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"` to be the latest version, currently 24.0.1 (you may need to run sdk manager to get the latest version)

Comment: @petey I update `buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"`to 24.0.1 but got `Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`
I used the 23.0.3 one but the problem still persists :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One cannot purchase his own app on Google Play on all his proper devices (devices associated with his developper account."
This is against policies